# Cross platform resourse sharing from API with ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, cors, ionic3, angular5

I was doing some front-end coding with ionic 3 which is using angular 5.
I am having an issue regarding the **Access Control Allow Origin**.

I am providing localhost:8100 as the option for **Access Control Allow Origin** to the server side but it is working only in the browser.

I think it will not work with the cross-platform API access.

Answer (score 0):

Cors is mostly serverside related. So if you want to make sure, to allow all resources, you need to specify in your serverside (whatever it is) to allow "*" (-> which stands for all)

Comment: Yes, i am doing the same but it is not accesing. Do i need to pass the same to server side in the headers?

Comment: Yes, you have to configure it on the backend